# Subscribe to valueChanges from input FormControl in FormGroup instead of FormControl directly

Tags: angular

I have the below "working" code in component.ts file (I have included the html code as well)

Please look at the commented lines in 3 places in the code. When I use FormControl variable directly then the valueChanges property works fine but when I access the FormControl variable from a FormGroup then I get `"ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute"`

What am I doing wrong here?

Code in app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <!--<form [formGroup]="searchFormGroup" >-->
       <h2>Observable events from formcontrol</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter input" [formControl]="searchInput">
    <!--</form>-->
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

  //searchFormGroup = new FormGroup({searchInput: new FormControl('')});
  searchInput: FormControl = new FormControl('');

  constructor(){

    //this.searchFormGroup.get('searchInput').valueChanges
    this.searchInput.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .subscribe(input => console.log(input));
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't build a form group like that. Here is how you build it.

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.searchFormGroup = fb.group({
    searchInput: ['']
  });
}
```

Comment: I used my constructor as below but still get the error:
`constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.searchFormGroup = fb.group({
      searchInput: ['']
    });

    this.searchFormGroup.get('searchInput').valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .subscribe(input => console.log(input));
  }`

Comment: Funny, **[because it works for me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-as1fz4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Oh yes, I have to use FormControlName which I didnt in my html. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it cannot work in RXjs 6.0, here is how you can write it with `Formcontrol`

```js
 // it works
 const searchInput = this.eleRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#search');
 fromEvent(searchInput, 'input').pipe(
   debounceTime(500)
)
.subscribe(input => {
   console.log(input);
});
```

Comment: I don't know how write it with Formcontrol in RXjs 6.0, this is another way to get it

Answer (score 0):

Started working fine after I used formControlName in the html code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="searchFormGroup" >
       <h2>Observable events from formcontrol</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter input" formControlName="searchInput">
    </form>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

  searchFormGroup = new FormGroup({'searchInput': new FormControl('')});
  //searchInput: FormControl = new FormControl('');

  constructor(){

    this.searchFormGroup.get('searchInput').valueChanges
    //this.searchInput.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .subscribe(input => console.log(input));
  }
}
```